# Pipeline flow get stuck at “Notifying stash” after finishing all stages

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket

All our CI projects are getting stuck in the Notify stash. eventually, it's passing, but we're trying to understand why it takes so much time. example:

```
17:03:01 Notifying Stash at "https://bitbucket"
17:15:44 Notified Stash for commit with id 925ceb567087f94c5b9d44d1330995860f11d1e5
```

what can cause such a delay? Bitbucket (Stash) Notifier Plugin version: 1.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We removed the OCP plugin configuration from Jenkins